# Microservices architecture using AWS

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, architecture, microservices

I am trying to build my microservices architecture using AWS, but the problem currently I am facing is that:

AWS api gateway cannot work similar to zuul api gateway for example:

```
http://{zuul-ip}/{MS_service_name}/{api_endpoint}
```

But for AWS API Gateway I have to make every API request first registered on AWS API Gateway.

Second Approach:

Using AWS ECS Fargate

Please let me know which is the better approach for building microservices on AWS.

Comment: Depends. Are your api function short running (below 15 minutes), do they require lots of dependencies, what programing language they are written?

Comment: @Marcin My Application is full fledged enterprise application Using spring boot in backend and angular in frontend. So what I want is to move my spring cloud tech microservices project is to AWS in all.

Answer (score 0):

When compared ECS Fargate vs API Gateway (using Lambda), predominantly Lambda is preferred in dev and pricing areas.

[Fargate vs. Lambda: Serverless in AWS](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/serverless-in-aws-lambda-vs-fargate#Fargate-vs.-Lambda-in-development)

When using API Gateway may be you can refer this:

[Using API Gateway as a Single Entry Point for Web Applications and API Microservices | AWS Architecture Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/using-api-gateway-as-a-single-entry-point-for-web-applications-and-api-microservices/)

Comment: Hi @Sabareesh, Thanks for the reply. But currently I am using spring cloud to build my microservices i.e.: Zuul for api gateway, eureka for service discovery and all the spring cloud stack for microservices. So what I want currently is deploy my microservices to the api gateway using best possible solution out there. I have tried to find any other architecture which is doing the same. But I dont want my project to be tightly coupled with aws as using lambda and aws api gateway makes it tightly coupled. So can you please let me know how to build my entire microservice project on aws.